# jquery settimeout function

Tags: jquery

I try to learn the magic behind ajax-php configuration so that i tried to implement a code like a clock via php. But, it seems i am still missing something. Here is what i did so far.

HTML(starting the clock when it is clicked)

```
<div id="bu" onclick="clock()">asccasascascsc</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var a = 0;
 function clock() {



     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "asd.php",
        data: {  
                'p':a
              },
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {

            $('#bu').html(data.p);
           setTimeout (clock    (),10000 );
        },
    });

}

 </script>
```

In here i wanted to replace "bu" with an integer 1 and create a loop to increase that number every 1 second. I know that setTimeout function works only once(I am a liar from where i read it:)) But i am calling it every single time.

PHP(asd.php)

```
<?php
$asd = $_GET['p'];
$asd++;
$data = array();

$data['p'] = $asd;


echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

PHP is where i did te increment part.

So, why is it not working? I am only seeing 1 but no more.
Note: I am pretty new as you can see:)

Comment: I think i direct the code to the clock() again where settimeout is. I think i call it again. Isnt it?

Comment: try this one:         success: function(data) {

            $('#bu').html(data.p);
           setTimeout ('clock    ();',10000 );
        },

Comment: This code **is wrong**. `setTimeout` should be passed a *function-object* (in this case the *result* of invoking `clock` is passed in, which is undefined). The end result is that `clock` runs "right away" and not after 10 seconds, as desired.

Comment: `setTimeout (clock(),10000 );` should be `setTimeout (clock,10000 );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = 0;

function clock() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "asd.php",
        data: {'p': a},
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            a = data.p;

            $('#bu').html(data.p);

            setTimeout(clock, 10000);
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

If you want to increase `$('#bu')` value, you need to increase `a`, which is what populate `$('#bu').html()` after each ajax rquest.

Comment: be careful it's `setTimeout(clock, 10000);`

Comment: Thanks, it is a copy paste of author question, and I forget this xD

Comment: I got that:) I thought php is changing "a" variable in javascript so that i dont need to change again. Thx:)